# Malformed line in the source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse), don't let me use update manager?

Tags: apt, software-sources

Here is the error hope i can get some help, i show you the update manager and the line of the error, if you need something else just ask for it.

```
E: Malformed line 59 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list (dist parse)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Error line:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ partner
```

Comment: just comment it out using # and try apt-get update again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct form of `canonical partner` repository address to be saved in `/etc/apt/sources.list` is following:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu <codename> partner
```

Just change the `codename` according to the release of Ubuntu you are using. For example the `codename` for `Ubuntu 12.04` is `precise`, so the correct form for Ubuntu 12.04 will be:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
```

The `codename` of 14.04 is `trusty`.

So replace the malformed line with the correct form.

Comment: but it doesnt allow me to save the chances

Comment: @StefanPopescu: Is the problem solved?